# Java, set ID for JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Is there anyway to set an id for a `JButton`. I'm used to it in Android.

I'm looking for something like the following:

```
newButton.setId(objectcounter);
```

Comment: *"I'm used to it in Android."*  Things are probably done differently in Android than in J2SE.  Get used to doing it the way the language usually does.  When in Rome..

Answer (score 16):

There is a property name which you could use:

```
newButton.setName(String.valueOf(objectCounter))
```

alternatively, you could use clientProperties which lets you store arbitrary values:

```
newButton.putClientProperty("id", Integer.valueOf(objectCounter))
```

To fetch the value from the client property map you'll need something like this.

```
Object property = newButton.getClientProperty("id");
if (property instanceof Integer) {
   int objectCounter = ((Integer)property);
   // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to use it togheter with the drop function.
Becuase I need to recognize diferent kinds of drops

Comment: These can be used for anything that requires a `String` or a `Map.Entry<Object, Object>`.

Comment: @user1321361 I've added an example of how to fetch the value